# RandomAccessFile читает только последную строку! Почему?

Tags: java, файлы, потоки-данных, java-stream

Вот код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    RandomAccessFile dataFile = new RandomAccessFile("data.txt", "r");
    int value;

    try {
        dataFile.seek(0);

        while (true) {
            value = dataFile.read();
            if (value != -1) {
                InOut.print((char) value);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Data file read error!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Вот контент файла `data.txt`:

```
Hello it's me.
I was wondering if after all these years
you'd like to meet.
```

Я получаю:

```
you'd like to meet.
```

Почему? Как получить содержание всего файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть-чуть упростил код. Все читает и выводит нормально. В чем проблема непонятно.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RandomAccessFile dataFile = new RandomAccessFile("data.txt", "r");

    while (true) {
        String textLine = dataFile.readLine();
        if (textLine != null) {
            System.out.println(textLine);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Hello it's me.
// I was wondering if after all these years
// you'd like to meet.
```